# Java BufferedImage getting red, green and blue individually

Tags: java, bufferedimage

The `getRGB()` method returns a single int. How can I get individually the red, green and blue colors all as the values between 0 and 255?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Java's [Color](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class can do the conversion:

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB());
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```

Comment: Creating a new `Color` instance of each pixel of an image generates a lot of garbage and can be *very* inefficient. If you plan to process every pixel of an image, it is far more efficient to obtain the RGB color of each pixel with `bufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)`, and extract the red, green and blue components as described in the answer by João Silva.

Answer (score 125):

A pixel is represented by a 4-byte (32 bit) integer, like so:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
^ Alpha  ^Red     ^Green   ^Blue
```

So, to get the individual color components, you just need a bit of binary arithmetic:

```
int rgb = getRGB(...);
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
int green = (rgb >>8 ) & 0x000000FF;
int blue = (rgb) & 0x000000FF;
```

This is indeed what the [`java.awt.Color`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/awt/Color.java.html) class methods do:

```
  553       /**
  554        * Returns the red component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB
  555        * space.
  556        * @return the red component.
  557        * @see #getRGB
  558        */
  559       public int getRed() {
  560           return (getRGB() >> 16) & 0xFF;
  561       }
  562   
  563       /**
  564        * Returns the green component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB
  565        * space.
  566        * @return the green component.
  567        * @see #getRGB
  568        */
  569       public int getGreen() {
  570           return (getRGB() >> 8) & 0xFF;
  571       }
  572   
  573       /**
  574        * Returns the blue component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB
  575        * space.
  576        * @return the blue component.
  577        * @see #getRGB
  578        */
  579       public int getBlue() {
  580           return (getRGB() >> 0) & 0xFF;
  581       }
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need some basic binary arithmetic to split it up:

```
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

(Or possibly the other way round, I honestly can't remember and the documentation isn't giving me an instant answer)

Answer (score 7):

For simple color manipulations, you can use

```
bufImg.getRaster().getPixel(x,y,outputChannels)
```

The outputChannels is an array for storing the fetched pixel. Its length depends on your image's actual channel count. For example, an RGB image has 3 channels; and an RGBA image has 4 channels.

This method has 3 output types: int, float and double.
To get a color value ranges from 0~255, your actual parameter outputChannels should be an int[] array.