# get colour of pixel in buffered image in the form of a color object

Tags: java, colors, pixel, bufferedimage

I have a buffered image, I want to get the colour of pixels at a specific coord. Is there a function that returns this in the form of a color object as opposed to RGB values?

This is in Java by the way..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the Color API.

You can create a Color object using the rgb value returned from the buffered image getRGB(...) method.