# Java - Red, Green, Blue to getRGB

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage

By calling `getRGB(int x, int y)` with a `BufferedImage` object, one gets a single, negative number.

How can I convert three different values (a red, a green, and a blue) into this single, negative number?

Comment: btw. every BufferedImage contains an array that holds all the pixels. If the BufferedImage is of type TYPE_INT_RGB that array will be an int array. So if you want to do a lot of pixel manipulation you can speed up your program by writing directly to that array. You can get it with int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java BufferedImage getting red, green and blue individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually)

Comment: @Michu93 This question asks the reverse of that, so this isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Color class:

```
new Color(r, g, b).getRGB()
```

Comment: This will use more resources than is necessary.

Comment: @Vulcan: agreed. But Color is open-source, so the OP could "steal" the code.

Comment: @JBNizet `int rgb = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue << 0);`

Answer (score 3):

BufferedImage ends up delegating to `java.awt.image.ColorModel` which uses the following code:

```
public int getRGB(Object inData) {
    return (getAlpha(inData) << 24)
        | (getRed(inData) << 16)
        | (getGreen(inData) << 8)
        | (getBlue(inData) << 0);
}
```

Modifying this to suit your needs is a trivial exercise.

Answer (score -1):

**JB Nizet's answer is great**, but it can be really slow when creating new objects of type 'Color' thousands of times. The simplest way would be:

```
int rgb = (red << 16 | green << 8 | blue)
```

As answered by [ByteBit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596140/3496570)

Comment: Did you steal this? lol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594046/converting-red-green-and-blue-to-rgb/24596140#24596140

Comment: I apologize for not giving reference to your answer.Now see edit