# Converting Red, Green and Blue to RGB

Tags: java, colors, bufferedimage

first I get Red, Green and Blue value from the following code,

```
  BufferedImage  image; 
  File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
     image = ImageIO.read(input);
     width = image.getWidth();
     height = image.getHeight();
      for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = (int)c.getRed();
           int green = (int)c.getGreen() ;
           int blue = (int)c.getBlue() ;
```

Here After Getting the Red, Green and Blue value from getRGB(), I want to Do some modification with the Red, Green and Blue value then again I want to convert it to same RGB value, or create a new 2d array RGB for the combined Red, Green and blue value. How to do it??
Any Guess.. Pls. Help

Comment: Have you tried this: new Color (red, green,blue); ?

Comment: But How to convert from Color to RGB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Red, Green, Blue to getRGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664011/java-red-green-blue-to-getrgb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java BufferedImage getting red, green and blue individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abdul's answer is great, but it can be really slow when creating new objects of class `Color` thousands of times. The simplest way would be:

```
int rgb = (red << 16 | green << 8 | blue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it will be:

```
new Color(red, green, blue).getRGB();
```

Also, as I see you are into Image Processing & Graphics, I suggest you [my blog](http://lcdtblog.blogspot.in/) where I have written quite a few articles on the topic.