# Java Color conversion

Tags: java, colors, type-conversion

I am having a problem using a method from `com.esri.arcgis.display.IColor`. The method is `IColor.getRGB()` which returns an `int`.

```
IColor symbolColor = symbol.getColor();
int colorInt = symbolColor.getRGB();
//TODO: get RGB values from colorInt
```

From the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/display/IColor.html):

> RGB returns the Long (ASCII) number calculated from the Red, Green and Blue color attributes.

I need to get the individual RGB values (standard 0-255) from this int somehow but I have been unable to find almost any information on converting from an ASCII number to RGB values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bit Shift and Bitwise operations to encode RGB values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277010/bit-shift-and-bitwise-operations-to-encode-rgb-values)

Comment: An int is an int is an int.  You might look at `colorInt` formatted as a decimal, say _10760562_, and it seems to make no sense as an RGB value, but if you format and print it as a hex value it will be `0xRRGGBB` — _10760562 == 0xA43172_, which clearly contains the individual red, green, and blue values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved by converting the int to hex, and then decoding the hex string using `Color.decode()` to obtain a `Color`. Using `Color` instance we can grab the individual RGB values.

```
IColor symbolColor = symbol.getColor();
int colorInt = symbolColor.getRGB();
String hexColor = Integer.toHexString(colorInt);
Color color = Color.decode("#"+hexColor);
int red = color.getRed();
int blue = color.getBlue();
int green = color.getGreen();
int alpha = color.getAlpha();`
```

Comment: This inefficient because you needlessly convert to String and back.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to convert these values by transferring their RGB integer.

```
int rgb = symbol.getColor().getRGB();
Color color = new Color(rgb);
int red = color.getRed();
int blue = color.getBlue();
int green = color.getGreen();
int alpha = color.getAlpha();
```

You might need to further investigate wether that `rgb` variable also contains the alpha values, in which case you want to use `new Color(rgb, true)` instead.

Comment: Using bit & operation and shift would be more straightforward and faster as shown by Andy Turner's link.

Comment: @dragon66 I would personally prefer a library usage over bitwise operations because I find them very unreadable. That's why I answered with this possibility.