# libGDX convert Color to RGBA float values

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I convert a Color value back to RGBA values.

For example I use

Color.rgba8888(r, g, b, a) to create an int value which corresponds to that color, how can I convert it back to the R G B A values?

Answer (score 0):

rgba8888 creates an int representation of that color. What you want instead is to use this constructor to make your color...

```
Color custom = new Color(1,.5f,0,1);
```

then you can extract the color values later with

```
custom.a 

r,g, and b
```

Answer (score 0):

This code Should work for an rgba8888 format it could work for other color formats [here's a link to a similar forearm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually) where i got the code idea from

> João Silva

```
int pixel = rgba8888 format

r = ( ( (all[5] & 0xff000000)>>24 ));
g +=  ( ((all[i] & 0x00ff0000)>>16)*weight[i]);
b +=  ( ((all[i] & 0x0000ff00)>>8)*weight[i]);
a +=  ( ((all[i] & 0x000000ff))*weight[i]);

pixel = ((int) r << 24 | (int)g << 16 | (int)b << 8 | (int)a );
```