# Getting the red, green and blue values of an image Java

Tags: java, image

So this method I wrote gets the mean and standard deviation of an image. I am trying to modify this to get the mean and standard deviation of the red, green and blue values of an image. But I am stumped on how to do to so. I tried to use a colorModel but I was getting nowhere. Could anyone give me some advice on how to modify this code to get the mean and standard deviation of the red, green and blue values?

```
    public static double redValues(BufferedImage image){
        Raster raster = image.getRaster();
        double mean = meanValue(image);
        double sumOfDiff = 0.0;
        Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(0, 0));
        int red = c.getRed();

         for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); ++y){
               for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); ++x){
                   double r = raster.getSample(x, y, red) - mean;                                  
                               sumOfDiff += Math.pow(r, 2);

                             }                   
                           }
        return sumOfDiff / ((image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()) - 1);
        }
```

But this still returns a mean brightness value. When I want to get the red value.

Comment: What's your problem?  Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually

Comment: You seem to consider only band 0 of your raster. The getPixel method returns an array for each component.

Comment: how do I get the getPixel method to return the red value?

Comment: @Neil my problem is its returning the over all mean of the image and not that of just the red values.