# How to use a picture of the screen without saving it in Java

Tags: java

I am working on creating a bot. What I need to do is find the color red, then click on it. I need to be able to use my function without saving a picture to my computer every half second. How can I use a picture of the screen without actually saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class provides a useful method for capturing a screenshot.

```
BufferedImage createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)
```

Once you have the image within the buffer you can perform other tasks on it like getting RGB color of the pixels within the image:

```
bufImg.getRaster().getPixel(x,y,outputChannels);
```

The following answer provides more info regarding that: [java bufferedimage getting red green and blue individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615522/java-bufferedimage-getting-red-green-and-blue-individually).

Hope this helps you further.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to use the `BufferedImage createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)`. If I want to save it to a variable `imageToSearch`, how would I do that?

Comment: The following [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=fiji-master/src-plugins/CLI_/src/main/java/CLI/Screenshot.java) shows how the `createScreenCapture` can be used. Within this example the screen capture is saved to a file but that would be in your case not necessary.